# Eclipse export uses same location and file name for different project

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I'm currently working on 4 different Java Project in the same workspace and whenever I export one of the project, is has the file location and file name as the last export I did, even when its from a different project.

Is there an option in eclipse to change the default file location and file name for the export for each project?

Example:

C:/projects/exports/foo.jar is set as the default location to export to even though I am exporting a different project that I want to be at C:/projects/exports/bar.jar

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you exporting the projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stock eclipse installation does not provide a way of setting default export locations.

Try `File -> Export` functionality stores the list of the last exported locations, you can re-use those.

Comment: edited question slightly, I want the default location for each project to be different so I don't have to constantly change the file locations, they're not as simple as changing the file name.

Comment: I did not realize this was a drop-down list. Thanks for saving me from retyping project names every time I need to export a different project.